# Mercurial log with one-liners

Tags: mercurial, command

The regular `hg log` command gives output with at least 4 lines per changeset. For example

```
changeset:   238:03a214f2a1cf
user:        My Name <my.name@example.com>
date:        Thu Aug 26 09:49:32 2010 +0200
summary:     Added tag v1.1 for changeset f22fd3974361
```

I mean to remember that there was a command to print a log in a more compact way what just had one line per changeset. A format that you could basically stick in a changelog.txt file and it would look nice.

Does that exist? Or am I mixing this with something I have seen with git or something else?

Comment: for the changelog style, try `log --style changelog` :)

Comment: Try this: hg log -T "\t{date|shortdate}\t[{rev}]\t{author|user}\t{desc}\n"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
 hg log --style compact
```

You can also use templates to display log out in different formats

```
hg help templates
```

In your case if you want to display only node ids do something like this

```
hg log --template "{node}\n"
```

Answer (score 54):

You can use `hg log` with a *--template* option, e.g.:

```
hg log --template '{node|short} | {date|isodatesec} | {author|user}: {desc|strip|firstline}\n'
```

This should show something like this (example from the GNU Emacs trunk I converted locally to an hg repository):

```
$ hg log --limit 5 --template '{node|short} | {date|isodatesec} | {author|user}: {desc|strip|firstline}\n'
36ab2e3f8ebd | 2010-09-08 16:54:00 +0200 | agustin: textmodes/ispell.el (ispell-valid-dictionary-list): Simplify logic.
9f3ac6d4a645 | 2010-09-08 16:42:54 +0200 | michael: Migrate to Tramp 2.2.  Rearrange load dependencies.
8c696d2a7695 | 2010-09-07 20:01:23 +0200 | agustin: Make sure original ispell arg list is initialized in (ispell-start-process).
b5f110747072 | 2010-09-07 06:23:16 +0000 | yamaoka: gnus-html.el (gnus-html-wash-tags, gnus-html-put-image): Mark cid and internal images as deletable by `W D D'.
b53cfb7d099e | 2010-09-07 01:20:19 +0000 | yamaoka: gnus-async.el (gnus-html-prefetch-images): Autoload it when compiling; (gnus-async-article-callback): Fix typo.
$
```

Once you have a nice template for one-line summaries of changesets, you can add a command *alias* in your `~/.hgrc` file like this:

```
[alias]
shortlog = log --template '{node|short} | {date|isodatesec} | {author|user}: {desc|strip|firstline}\n'
```

With the alias installed you can now type `hg shortlog`, `hg short` or even `hg shor` (to uniquely identify `hg shortlog` instead of `hg showconfig`) and all the usual `log' command-options.  For instance it should now be possible to type:

```
$ hg short -r 100:103
db9f8efcf689 | 1990-09-14 19:07:14 +0000 | jimb: *** empty log message ***
5874bf15e07d | 1990-09-19 18:22:41 +0000 | gnulists: Initial revision
797d304414fd | 1990-09-27 21:17:59 +0000 | mtr: Initial revision
b2656b7830e4 | 1990-10-09 02:52:33 +0000 | rms: *** empty log message ***
$
```

or even things that use tag names (example from the mercurial crew repository itself):

```
keramida@kobe:/hg/mercurial/crew$ hg short -r 1.4 -r 1.5 -r 1.6
31ec469f9b55 | 2009-11-16 21:25:36 +0100 | mg: i18n-ja: fixed bad indentation
ff2704a8ded3 | 2010-03-05 17:24:52 -0600 | mpm: mq: drop -Q in favor of --mq only
f786fc4b8764 | 2010-06-29 12:12:34 +0200 | mads: log: follow filenames through renames (issue647)
keramida@kobe:/hg/mercurial/crew$
```

Comment: For more information, see [this guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html), and there's also `hg help templates`.

Answer (score 6):

To get the description on one line even if original comment contains multiple line combine a splitlines and join function like below:

```
{join(splitlines(desc), ' ')}
```

Here is an example i'm using to extract data as CSV:

```
hg log --template "{node};{date|shortdate};{branch};{author};{join(splitlines(desc), ' ')};{diffstat};files: {join(files, ', ')}\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone wants something similar to `git log --oneline`:

```
hg log --template '{rev} {tags} {desc|strip|firstline}\n' -l 5
```

```
2737 tip Lint: trailing-whitespace
2736  Hack: temporary auto-subscription on login
2735  Fix: Encoding wasn't passed in memory metrics
```

Replace `{rev}` with `{node|short}` if you want hashes (but in Mercurial revision numbers are traditionally used).