# Cut off the "desc" at N characters in hg log output with templates

Tags: mercurial, hg-log

I'm trying to create a custom template for `hg log` with a part that shows the first N (e.g. 72) characters of the first line. Based off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3681586/419956) to a different question I've gotten so far:

```
hg log --template '{desc|strip|firstline}\n'
```

Now I'm trying to limit that bit to a certain number of characters. However, [the corresponding template usage docs](https://selenic.com/hg/help/templates) yields no search results for "substring", "left", etc. I've tried a few things, including

```
hg log --template '{desc|strip|firstline|strip|50}\n'
```

and just for testing also

```
hg log --template '{desc|strip|50}\n'
```

but they give an error:

> hg: parse error: unkown function '50'

I'd hazard a guess that what I want is possible, but I just seem unable to find the appropriate syntax. **How can I construct a template that outputs the first line of a commit message, up to a maximum of N characters?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expressions and the `sub()` function to accomplish that. For example:

```
hg log --template '{sub("^(.{0,50})(.|\n)*","\\1",desc)}\n'
```

The `sub()` function takes three arguments, the pattern, the replacement, and the string to be processed. In this example, we use a group that captures anywhere from 0 to 50 characters (except newline), followed by another pattern that slurps up the rest (so that it gets discarded). The replacement string simply shows the first group, and we use `desc` as the input. Simply change the `50` in the example above with the width you actually want.

If you don't want descriptions cut off mid-word, you can also use `fill()` in conjunction with `firstline`. Here, `fill()` will break the input into lines, then we use the first line of the output. Example:

```
hg log --template '{fill(desc,"50")|firstline}\n'
```

Note that words with dashes in them may still be cut off, since `fill()` considers the position after a dash to be a valid choice for a linebreak.

Comment: Hmm, judging by your description, the latter is what I'm looking for. It's giving me "fill expects an integer width" though (Win 8.1, 64bit, hg 3.4.1), but that may be a different problem. Will look into that in a bit.

Comment: This usually happens when you don't put the width in quotes (or if you accidentally use the same quotes for the width as for the entire command line argument).

Comment: I've tried with and without *double* quotes, in both cases I get the error. However, if I *switch* the quotes around (`"{fill(desc,'50')|firstline}\n"`) it does work! Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that I used Powershell.